# Testing code when a dependency is not available

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

I have to write and test some code where a dependency will only be available once my code is deployed. Philosophically I am ok with this because I want to mock everything provided by the dependency anyway. But I am having trouble with monkeypatching at the right spot. Here's some code:

```
# my_package/handlers.py

from unavailable.package_name import SomeBaseClass

class MyClass(SomeBaseClass):
    def do_something(self):
        return True
```

To test the do_something method I need to import and create an instance of MyClass, which will in turn attempt to import SomeBaseClass from unavailable.package_name, which is from a dependency I am unable to install in my testing environment.

Is there a way to monkeypatch this totally unavailable import before importing my_package.handlers? Or do I need "something" installed to provide that import so it's available for overriding?

Comment: Thank you! I've been searching all afternoon. Apparently I needed to include contest.py in my search and I would have found this.